# Embedding Plotly interactive graphs into blog without losing animation

Tags: python, plotly

I want to embed an animated graph (something similar to [this one](https://plot.ly/create/?fid=AashitaK:20)) in my blog. I am unable to render an animated graph using the share or any other option suggested [here](https://help.plot.ly/embed-graphs-in-websites/). Is there a way I can do this? The graph is originally created using plotly offline in Jupyter notebook. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the iframe provided in the plotly online editor embed options, past the code given below.

```
<iframe width="900" height="800" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="//plot.ly/~kai1992cool/20.embed"></iframe>
```

Please do try and let me know how it goes!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. However, my question is not about rendering the graph in Jupyter Notebook. The graph itself was generated in a Jupyter Notebook and I want to embed it in a blog. I know the usual way to embed a plotly graph by downloading it as html, however in this case the html file is too big because of animation. So the question is specifically about embedding animated plotly graph in a blog.

Comment: @AashitaKesarwani Is this blog made with wordpress or blogger? why can't you just use the iframe inside the blog content?

Comment: @AashitaKesarwani If you place the content `<iframe width="900" height="800" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="//plot.ly/~kai1992cool/20.embed"></iframe>` inside the page, it will render from my understanding!

Comment: I am hosting the blog on Github Pages using Jekyll. Thanks for the last comment, it worked! I was trying to use the html, but the page build-up would fail. It worked with embedding the iframe! Thank you so much for helping me to fix the problem.